# JAVA Cipher decrypt encrypted Chinese text, sometimes fail to bring back to Chinese text again and get error like ÃƒÆ’Ã‚

Tags: java, encryption

So i make a simple program that encrypt people text as string and write it to file.txt
and if someone want to read the data, the program will get file.txt as string
and decrypt the data

this is the backend program
where user type/input text or read the text is at web (just simple textarea)

everything is fine and good in testing even in production,
but error happen when someone start to insert Chinese text

the odd thing is, is not always error

i mean user when writing document and use some Chinese text, it going ok, he save it, not change it, keep adding new text
he still can read the text, save it, read it and writing the other day
but one day he can't read the Chinese text, only the Chinese text
mostly he writing English text document, maybe someone name in Chinese he can't write in English, so he use Chinese text

i even try to loop encrypt decrypt data process, about 100 times and it still succeeded to encrypt and decrypt back to Chinese text

so i don't really know what cause the error

here's my code

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class DecriptEncript {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String secretKey = "zxc";

        //String originalString = "i";
        String originalString = "你好吗";
         
         
        for(int i = 0 ; i <100;i++) { // when i test try 100 times

            String encryptedString = DecriptEncript.encrypt(originalString, secretKey) ;
            String decryptedString = DecriptEncript.decrypt(encryptedString, secretKey) ;
            System.out.println(originalString);
            System.out.println(encryptedString);
            System.out.println(decryptedString);
        }
    }
    
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;
 
    public static void setKey(String myKey) 
    {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); 
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 
    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
 
    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the error is when the program want to bring back to Chinese text
"not always error" and when error happen the program showing text like

Ãƒâ€¦Ã¢¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€Ã¢â (just randomly take from all the error)

i don't know how to bring back user data to text Chinese from this text error
and i don't know the Chinese text he input

BTW this is my first time use Cipher decrypt encrypted
so if you ask me why choose "SHA-1" or "UTF-8" or Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
honestly i just copy from someone code at the internet

thank you for help

Comment: Have you tried to force UTF-8 encoding when converting back to string? You are using "return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));", a solution could be "return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);"

Comment: You should describe "sometimes" more precisely. Does the error occur unreproducibly for the **same** input sometimes and sometimes not or does it occur reproducibly for some chinese characters and for some not?

Comment: @MichaelFehr well i'll try it, and see if it work,..maybe a couple day, thanks btw

Comment: @user9014097 user when type Chinese text, it going well,...he can still read his data, keep it and not change it, just add new text, keep writing, save it, read,.. writing, save it, but i don't know excatly when,.. the chinese text he save before get error, only the chinese text

Comment: @user9014097 i'll add this to description

Comment: What @MichaelFehr wrote is very likely the issue. This line will fail on any device where UTF-8 is not the platform default encoding (most notably, almost all Windows systems). Make sure you explicitly provide the encoding at every point where you convert `byte[]` to `String` and vice versa.

Comment: hi @MichaelFehr thank you and it's been 7 months since i updated my code and till now, i haven't heard any complaints yet, i'd like to vote for you as an answer but this is just a comment, i saw other people answer too but your first

Comment: Thank you for the good news, paradisa. It's OK to mark the answer of @Olivier Grégoire as the accepted one as it is a more complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You encode in UTF-8, but you decode in whatever encoding the platform is configured.

So just force UTF-8 in the decipher as well.

```
    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            
            // Note the extraction for readability
            byte[] deciphered = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt))
            
            // Here, use UTF-8
            return new String(deciphered, "UTF-8");

            // Or better:
            // return new String(deciphered, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually i've got it for quite a while, from @MichaelFehr comment, because his answer is a comment cant mark it as an answer, but he recommend yours as answer, because it more complete answer,..

hope people who search this topic can find this